# Force Entity Framework to NOT use NCLOB datatype

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle11g, asp.net-identity

So I am using ASP.NET Identity + Entity Framework and whenever I generate the database from code, Many columns types are NCLOB which are very heavy.

Now there are several ways to modify the types of the columns such as `HasColumnType` method or by setting StringLength attribute or by configuring the modelbuilder to give a `HasMaxLength` attribue for those who don't have it already.

The problem with identity is that some columns specially for IDs are set rather later.

So in the migration file I have this:

```
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 1, scale: 0),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
```

Now after applying this code that I found online:

```
            modelBuilder.Properties()
          .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
                      p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), false).Length == 0 )
          .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(2000));
```

The migration code becomes like this:

```
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 2000),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 1, scale: 0),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(maxLength: 2000),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(maxLength: 2000),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(maxLength: 2000),
```

If you have noticed, the `UserID` was already set to a certain value, but even so it changed.

Is there a workaround for it to not change?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just had to set their properties manually for now hoping for a more automatic solution.

```cs
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId").HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId").HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles").Property(p=> p.RoleId).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles").Property(p => p.UserId).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins").Property(p=> p.UserId).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins").Property(p => p.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins").Property(p => p.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims").Property(p => p.UserId).HasMaxLength(128); ;
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles").Property(p => p.Id).HasMaxLength(128);
```